# Error when trying to include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get started with controller tests, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code, and the error it's producing:

```
require 'test_helper'

class InvProcure::UserImportsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  test "should get index" do
    user = users(:foobars_admin)
    sign_in(:user, user)
    get inv_procure_user_imports_path
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
    /home/blaine/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/test/controller_helpers.rb:42:in `setup_controller_for_warden'
```

It looks like the error might be happening when including devise test helpers, or when calling `sign_in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise/Devise/Test/ControllerHelpers

> `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` provides a facility to test controllers in isolation when using `ActionController::TestCase` allowing you to quickly sign_in or sign_out a user. Do not use `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` in integration tests.

You are inheriting the integration test class instead of the controller test class which is the default for controller tests now (From Rails 5 the controller tests are generated with the parent class as `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` instead of `ActionController::TestCase`). `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` was built for `ActionController::TestCase` and not for integration tests.

You can instead try to use `Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` which should have similar methods for integration tests.

Document: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise/Devise/Test/IntegrationHelpers

Comment: Ok, the controller test I posted in my question was auto-generated by rails under `test/controllers/xyz_controller_test.rb`, and the generated code inherited from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` by default, is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Yes that is correct, you need to include integration helpers instead

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was confused because elsewhere on the internet someone said to use `ActionDispatch::ControllerTest`, but now I see that class has been deprecated.